# Why inconsistent results using subtraction in reduce?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given the following:

```
val rdd = List(1,2,3)
```

I assumed that `rdd.reduce((x,y) => (x - y))` would return `-4` (i.e. `(1-2)-3=-4`), but it returned `2`.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the RDD source code (and [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#reduce(scala.Function2))):

```
/**
* Reduces the elements of this RDD using the specified commutative and
* associative binary operator.
*/
def reduce(f: (T, T) => T): T
```

`reduce` is a monoidal reduction, thus it assumes the function is **commutative** and **associative**, meaning that the order of applying it to the elements is not guaranteed.

Obviously, your function `(x,y)=>(x-y)` isn't commutative nor associative.

In your case, the reduce might have been applied this way:

```
3 - (2 - 1) = 2
```

or

```
1 - (2 - 3) = 2
```

Comment: Ok I see now. But doesn't this make the results of such functions a bit unpredictable? (got my answer from @elm :) thank you very much guys!)

Comment: Only if you don't follow the rules... :) Seriously now, when you want to _parallelize_ your computation, you must "pay the price" by making your algorithm distributable, e.g. allowing Spark (or any other framework, this applies to Hadoop reducers too) to perform some of the computation on each node, and then aggregate the results. This is exactly what happens here - to perform `reduce` efficiently, each partition will be reduced and then all of these intermediate results will be reduced again - if your function can't handle that, computation will have to be sequential, which beats the point...

Answer (score 2):

You can easy replace subtraction  *v1 - v2 - ... - vN* with *v1 - (v2 + ... + vN)*, so your code can look like

```
val v1 = 1
val values = Seq(2, 3)
val sum = sc.paralellize(values).reduce(_ + _)
val result = v1 - sum
```

Answer (score 1):

As aforementioned by @TzachZohar the function must satisfy the two properties so that the parallel computation is sound; by *collecting* the rdd, `reduce` relaxes the properties required in the function, and so it produces the result from a sequential (non parallel) computation, namely,

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 3)

rdd.collect.reduce((x,y) => (x-y))
Int = -4
```

Comment: rdd.collect and then reduce on driver side may be not the best idea, if you have a lot of data

Comment: @VitaliyKotlyarenko Definitely true, this is just to contrast function properties needed for parallel versus sequential computations.

Comment: Worth to mention that the two `reduce` functions are from "different" worlds -- Spark's and Scala's.